# Output data from multiple MySql tables with PhP

Tags: php, mysql, output

I have 3 MySql tables:

1. "quiz" with columns 'id', 'quiz_name', 'description', 'quiz_number';
2. "questions" with columns 'id', 'question', 'question_number', 'quiz_number';
3. "answers" with columns 'id', 'answer', 'answer_letter', 'question_number', 'quiz_number'.

I want to output every quiz separately with all the questions and the answers its contents, following this structure:

**Questionnaire 1**

1. Question 1

   a. Answer 1
   b. Answer 2
   c. Answer 3
   d. Answer 4
   e. Answer 5
2. Question 2

   a. Answer 1
   b. Answer 2
   c. Answer 3
   d. Answer 4
   e. Answer 5

etc.

**Questionnaire 2**

1. Question 1

   a. Answer 1
   b. Answer 2
   c. Answer 3
   d. Answer 4
   e. Answer 5
2. Question 2

   a. Answer 1
   b. Answer 2
   c. Answer 3
   d. Answer 4
   e. Answer 5

etc.

I have tried for a few days and I can't succeed. All I got is all the answers below all the questions... I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: What actually have you tried? Post your code, it would be easier to tell whats wrong

Comment: Am not quite familiar with the raw php myself, I use laravel framework, whereby, you could do all these with just proper relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can do a query with all the 3 tables and information, but that's not the correct approach. Having a table with the quiz, questions and answers will have a lot of repetition and will lose the purpose.

You should query for the lists of quizes, then query que questions and do a table with all the answers.

Those are my 2 cents.